# Error when call In App Purchase - swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I facing problem when calling function as below (OR purchase product):

> func restoreCompletedTransactions(){
>           SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions();
>       }

It return error as below:

> Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store,
>   SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=503}

What is the bugs?
How can I solved it?

Thanks

Comment: Any news about it?

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue before ! It is very easily fixed. Make sure you log out of the app store with your regular account and from iTunes.

Next time you test your IAP on your device, log in with your sandbox account. It should work.

Also, if that doesn't fix your problem, have a look at this: [My IAP isn't working. Bugs at func Paymentqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741619/my-iap-isnt-working-bugs-at-func-paymentqueue)

It contains my code for IAPs (which works) and some tips to fix some issues. I hope this answer was helpful ;)

Here is the full IAP code :

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit


class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate,GADBannerViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet var outRemoveAds: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var outRestorePurchases: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("val") != nil {
            print("Has a value.")
            banner.removeFromSuperview()
            bannerGoogle.removeFromSuperview()
            outRemoveAds.removeFromSuperview()
            outRestorePurchases.removeFromSuperview()
            removeInterFrom = 1
        }
        else {
            print("No Value.")
        }

        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()){
            print("IAP is enabled, loading...")
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects:"IAP id")
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }
        else{
            print("Please enable IAPS")

        }

    }


    //IAP Ads

    @IBAction func removeAds(sender: UIButton) {
        for product in list{
            let prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if (prodID == "IAP id"){
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break
            }
        }
    }
    @IBAction func restorePurchases(sender: UIButton) {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }


    //IAP Functions

    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()

    func removeAds(){
        banner.removeFromSuperview()
        bannerGoogle.removeFromSuperview()
        outRemoveAds.removeFromSuperview()
        outRestorePurchases.removeFromSuperview()
        let theValue = 10
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(theValue, forKey: "val")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    func buyProduct(){
        print("Buy: "+p.productIdentifier)
        let pay = SKPayment (product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
    }

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("Product Request")
        let myProduct = response.products

        for product in myProduct{
            print("Product Added")
            print(product.productIdentifier)
            print(product.localizedTitle)
            print(product.localizedDescription)
            print(product.price)

            list.append(product as SKProduct)
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Add Payment")

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions{
            let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            print(trans.error)
            switch trans.transactionState{
            case .Purchased:
                print("IAP unlocked")
                print(p.productIdentifier)

                let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
                switch prodID{
                case "IAP id":
                    print("Remove Ads")
                    removeAds()
                default:
                    print("IAP not setup")
                }
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            case .Failed:
                print ("Buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            default:
                print("default: Error")
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("Purchases Restored")

        _ = []
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction

            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID{
            case "IAP id":
                print("Remove Ads")
                removeAds()
            default:
                print("IAP not setup")
            }


        }
    }
    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction){
        print("Finshed Transaction")
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Remove Transaction")
    }
}
```

Put:

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
```

in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear